# How to make JavaScript animation series pause and continue?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm looking for some guidance regarding this JavaScript animation. What happens currently is you will click on the image, and it changes to another image. If you keep clicking on the image quickly, it looks like a flipbook basically. Anyway, I want to make it so when I click on the image once, the images continuously change, making it look like an animation. If I click on the the image again, I want the animation to pause. I want this to operate so when it gets to the last image, it just continues from the beginning (how it is right now)

My professor suggested using a global variable to save the current states, like pausing or playing, current frame being played. I'm just started to learn JavaScript so any guidance would be extremely helpful.

```
//I have a folder called images that contains jpg's called frame0, frame1, frame2, etc...

<html>   
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript Animation</title>      
      <script type = "text/javascript">
            var imgObj = null;
            
            function init() {
               imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
               imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
               imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
            }
        function nextFrame() {
        nextFrame.counter = ++nextFrame.counter || 1;
        if(nextFrame.counter==11) {
        nextFrame.counter=1;
        }
            imgObj.src = 'images/frame' + nextFrame.counter + '.jpg';
        //alert('frame' + nextFrame.counter + '.jpg');
        }
        window.onload = init;
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body>   
      <form>
         <img id="myImage" src="images/frame0.jpg" input type="image" src="images/frame0.jpg" alt="Submit" onclick="nextFrame();" />
      </form>      
   </body>
</html>
```